# Cannot create new row in Dashboard (Cloudboost)

Tags: dashboard, newrow, cloudboost

I cannot create a new row through dashboard, see the attached image:

[image: Error alert message says: Unique constraint violated]

Error alert message says: Unique constraint violated.

It seems, that the autogenerated id is not beeing generated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! it was my fault. I had a the unique flag set on **label** column.